# Progress rate during map phase (LATE scheduler) - Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, progress, scheduler

I am trying to find out the progress rate of the map tasks. If someone can help me out it will be great !! Thanks !!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways we monitor the progress of the Map and Reduce on a job.

The first is the web interface.

`http://pdhadoop1:50030` where `pdhadoop1` is your namenode machine.

The otherway is from inside the job driver, it is possible to output to the console (or elsewhere)
After the job is submitted, we enter a `while` loop and check against `job.isComplete()`. Inside the loop we do

```
System.out.println(String.format("Progress of Page views ETL Job %s:", job.getJobID().toString()));
System.out.println(String.format("\tMap : %f, Reduce %F", job.mapProgress(), job.reduceProgress()));
```

Then we `Thread.sleep(60000)` and the loop keeps going until the job is complete.

With both of these I am able to watch the progress of the map and reduce components of a job.

The web interface allows looking at logs and additional useful information. Counters, records, bytes... A very nice feature.

I hope that helps. :)

EDIT: This wiki page http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/WebApp_URLs has these URLs listed

The Job Tracker can be found at http://localhost:50030
The Task Tracker can be found at http://localhost:50060
The NameNode / Filesystem / log browser can be found at http://localhost:50070
The SecondaryNameNode can be found at http://localhost:50090

I *think* localhost is dependent on the URL you want to look at. I haven't played with all of them, I generally just use 50030 and 50070; Both of which I point at my namenode.

Comment: Or instead of writing a while loop you can simply call Job.waitForCompletion(true).

Comment: @Thomas Jungblut: Does `waitForCompletion(true) output the progress? AFAIK using the loop allows for control over output. I'm running 4 jobs and the loop allows control over the ordering of the output. :)

Comment: yes, it prints the current progress into STDOUT or LOG whatever is configured.

Comment: @Thomas Jungblut: I was not aware of that. Good to know. :-D

Comment: Wow .... Thanks a lot for the information. I knew about the web API but I dont want to use that. I want to use it as a part of my program. So I will use the latter. I have used as a workload but I have never used the API. I will take some time to figure out and get back if I have any problems. Thanks a lot for the information. I really appreciate it !!